# jQuery fadeOut closing wrong div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using this read more function: https://css-tricks.com/text-fade-read-more/

I am using this feature four times on my page. When I open one div and then another, and then go to close the first div, the second div is closed instead and after than the first div can't be closed.

Is it possible to ensure that the close feature closes the associated div?

Here is the jQuery:

```
<script>
var jq14 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // your logic

        var mq = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 767px)");

        var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;

        $(".fade-box .button-read-on").click(function () {

            totalHeight = 0

            $el = $(this);
            $p = $el.parent();
            $up = $p.parent();
            $ps = $up.find("p:not('.read-more')");

            // measure how tall inside should be by adding together heights of all inside paragraphs (except read-more paragraph)
            $ps.each(function () {
                totalHeight += $(this).outerHeight();
                // FAIL totalHeight += $(this).css("margin-bottom");
            });

            $up
                .css({
                    // Set height to prevent instant jumpdown when max height is removed
                    "height": $up.height(),
                    "max-height": 9999
                })
                .animate({
                    "height": totalHeight
                })
                .click(function () {
                    //After expanding, click paragraph to revert to original state
                    $p.fadeIn();

                    if (mq.matches) {
                        $up.animate({
                            "height": 190
                        });
                    } else {
                        $up.animate({
                            "height": 210
                        });
                    }

                });

            // fade out read-more
            $p.fadeOut();

            // prevent jump-down
            return false;

        });
    });
}(jq14));
```

And here is the close function in the HTML:

```
<p class="close">Close <img src="img/arrow-up.png"></p>
```

I think the problem is that I am using this close HTML numerous times on the page.

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Here is another fun way to do this with .wrap()  http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/rgvdL

Comment: Thanks I might look into this as an alternative. How would I add a close feature to it?

Comment: This particular case would be for mobile phones where close would almost be more annoying. BUT I just added an answer for you, and I'll include a close in that pen.

Answer (score 4):

Move this line

```
var $el, $ps, $up, totalHeight;
```

after this line

```
$(".fade-box .button-read-on").click(function () {
```

After you click the first one, the variables are set to the correct value for the fist one, but when you click the second one, they are overwritten. Changing their scope makes it so that you can have multiple instances of each variable that each correspond to the right element.

Comment: Great, thanks for your quick response. It almost worked. The first one now closes but the read more fade effect is not showing and the text is now cut off

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick exercise to see if there is a more readable way. If you use something like `rel` it will be clear what is for JS as opposed to CSS styles. It hides the content with a integer height of your choosing and targets whatever selector you would want. For *each* item you want this to happen to... It will grab it's natural height and store it in a data-attribute on the element. Then when you click the read-more, it will take that height and use it for animation.

http://codepen.io/sheriffderek/pen/rLYdky

### markup

```
<article rel='reveal'>

    <h2>Thing 1</h2>

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Fugiat quaerat molestiae voluptas soluta officia veniam ad, alias fuga sit, adipisci, similique harum odio eos vel. Et, numquam, error. Doloribus, ipsa!</p>
    
    ...
    
    <button>More</button>

</article>
```

### JavaScript

```
(function() { // closure for this program // so nothing leaks...
    
    var hideContent = function(element, maxHeight) {
        $('[rel="reveal"]').each( function() {
            var naturalHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
            $(this).data('height', naturalHeight);
            $(this).css('height', maxHeight);
        });
    };

    $('[rel="reveal"]').on('click', function() {
        var naturalHeight = $(this).data('height');
        var speed = naturalHeight*2; // relative to height maybe?
        $(this).find('button').fadeOut();
        $(this).animate({
            'height': naturalHeight
        }, speed);
    });

    hideContent('[rel="reveal"]', 200);

})();
```